# Will a galvanized container leach Zinc and "Trim" the roots? Are there other effects?

Tags: raised-beds, containers

I have heard that a galvanized container such as [this one](http://www.tractorsupply.com/livestock/livestock-equipment/stock-tanks-accessories/stock-tanks/oval-galvinized-stock-tank-2-ft-w-x-6-ft-l-x-2-ft-h-169-gal-capacity-2177227) for a raised bed will leach zinc and "trim" the roots. What do they mean by this?

Would the increased zinc be bad for raising food plants? I was planning on growing bamboo in them but having a couple more for  food plots would be awful convenient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Zinc should not be a problem it may raise zinc levels by a minimal to negligible amount. Some galvanized containers may contain cadmium, although not so much a risk in plant uptake, but you will want to make sure you wash your hands and crops well before consuming.